# Group-by array on 2 properties with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, reduce

I want to group an array of objects by 2 properties. How can i manage to do that?

I got this array:

```
[
    {
        "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
        "apelido": "Beatrice",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T15:00:00",
        "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Davi",
        "apelido": "Davi",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T14:00:00",
        "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Kai",
        "apelido": "Martins",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T13:30:00",
        "Servico": "Barba Completa"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
        "apelido": "Beatrice",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T09:30:00",
        "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
        "apelido": "Beatrice",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T09:00:00",
        "Servico": "Alongamento de Cabelo"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
        "apelido": "Beatrice",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T08:00:00",
        "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Estevan Alves",
        "apelido": "Estevan",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-25T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-25T08:40:00",
        "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Kai",
        "apelido": "Martins",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-25T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-25T08:30:00",
        "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Estevan Alves",
        "apelido": "Estevan",
        "dt_extrato": "2020-05-25T00:00:00",
        "dt_inicio": "2020-05-25T08:00:00",
        "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
    }
]
```

And i want do transform it into this object:

```
{
"2020-05-26T00:00:00": [{
    "Beatrice Mattos": [
        {
            "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
            "apelido": "Beatrice",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T15:00:00",
            "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
        },
        {
            "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
            "apelido": "Beatrice",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T09:30:00",
            "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
        },
        {
            "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
            "apelido": "Beatrice",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T09:00:00",
            "Servico": "Alongamento de Cabelo"
        },
        {
            "nome": "Beatrice Mattos",
            "apelido": "Beatrice",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T08:00:00",
            "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
        }
    ],
    "Davi": [
        {
            "nome": "Davi",
            "apelido": "Davi",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T14:00:00",
            "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
        }
    ],
    "Kai": [
        {
            "nome": "Kai",
            "apelido": "Martins",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T13:30:00",
            "Servico": "Barba Completa"
        }
    ]
}],
"2020-05-25T00:00:00": [{
    "Kai": [
        {
            "nome": "Kai",
            "apelido": "Martins",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-26T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-26T13:30:00",
            "Servico": "Barba Completa"
        },
        {
            "nome": "Kai",
            "apelido": "Martins",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-25T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-25T08:30:00",
            "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
        }
    ],
    "Estevan Alves": [
        {
            "nome": "Estevan Alves",
            "apelido": "Estevan",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-25T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-25T08:40:00",
            "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
        },
        {
            "nome": "Estevan Alves",
            "apelido": "Estevan",
            "dt_extrato": "2020-05-25T00:00:00",
            "dt_inicio": "2020-05-25T08:00:00",
            "Servico": "Corte Masculino"
        }
    ]
}]
```

}

My goal is to group the services by date and name. I was only able group by one ore another, not both.

To group by the field 'name', i'm using the following code:

```
 this.name_group = this.array.reduce((data, object) => {
      data[object.nome] = [...data[object.nome] || [], object];
      return data;
    }, {});
```

To group by the field 'dt_extrato', i'm using the following code:

```
 this.date_group = this.array.reduce((data, object) => {
      data[object.dt_extrato] = [...data[object.dt_extrato] || [], object];
      return data;
    }, {});
```

But i can't manage to group both, nested. Is this possible using only reduce?

Thanks

Comment: do you really want arrays for groups with a single object?

Comment: i don't know if its the best aproach. I'm using Angular and going to change the financial statement screen of an app. Currently is listing all of the services, now they want it grouped by date and professional. Since the data comes from the server in the form of an array, i thoght that was best to transform it right into the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to get nested objects without an array inbetween, you could take this approach with an array of nesting keys.

```js
var data = [{ nome: "Beatrice Mattos", apelido: "Beatrice", dt_extrato: "2020-05-26T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-26T15:00:00", Servico: "Corte Masculino" }, { nome: "Davi", apelido: "Davi", dt_extrato: "2020-05-26T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-26T14:00:00", Servico: "Corte Masculino" }, { nome: "Kai", apelido: "Martins", dt_extrato: "2020-05-26T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-26T13:30:00", Servico: "Barba Completa" }, { nome: "Beatrice Mattos", apelido: "Beatrice", dt_extrato: "2020-05-26T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-26T09:30:00", Servico: "Corte Masculino" }, { nome: "Beatrice Mattos", apelido: "Beatrice", dt_extrato: "2020-05-26T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-26T09:00:00", Servico: "Alongamento de Cabelo" }, { nome: "Beatrice Mattos", apelido: "Beatrice", dt_extrato: "2020-05-26T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-26T08:00:00", Servico: "Corte Masculino" }, { nome: "Estevan Alves", apelido: "Estevan", dt_extrato: "2020-05-25T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-25T08:40:00", Servico: "Corte Masculino" }, { nome: "Kai", apelido: "Martins", dt_extrato: "2020-05-25T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-25T08:30:00", Servico: "Corte Masculino" }, { nome: "Estevan Alves", apelido: "Estevan", dt_extrato: "2020-05-25T00:00:00", dt_inicio: "2020-05-25T08:00:00", Servico: "Corte Masculino" }],
    keys = ['dt_extrato', 'nome'],
    result = data.reduce((r, object) => {
        keys
            .reduce((group, key, index, { length }) =>
                group[object[key]] = group[object[key]] || (index + 1 === length
                    ? []
                    : {}
                ), r)
            .push(object);
        return r;
    }, {});
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you ver much! I was strugling with this